# What is the difference between service and systemctl?

Tags: service, systemctl

Maybe this is a trivial question, but it is not totally clear to me. On one of our servers we have some background processes running which were started with `service` and some others which were started with `systemctl`, like this:

```
$ service nginx start
$ systemctl start gunicorn
```

What is the difference between the two commands? Which one is the preferred way to deal with background services? How to configure the preferred command?

Comment: there is a very good explanation [there](https://askubuntu.com/a/903405/840341)

Comment: The painful part of this, some say service is 'defunct' and if it is not, why the hell do they change the order of arguments as with 'find/grep/locate' etc...no consistency within linux releases :(

Answer (score 105, accepted):

`service` is an "high-level" command used for starting and stopping services in different unixes and linuxes. Depending on the "lower-level" service manager, `service` redirects on different binaries.

For example, on CentOS 7 it redirects to `systemctl`, while on CentOS 6 it directly calls the relative `/etc/init.d` script. On the other hand, in older Ubuntu releases it redirects to `upstart`

`service` is adequate for basic service management, while directly calling `systemctl` give greater control options.

Answer (score 24):

`systemctl` is basically a more powerful version of `service`.

With `service` you can only do commands related to the service (i.e. `status`, `reload`, `restart`) whereas with `systemctl` you can use more advanced commands such as:

`systemctl is-failed name.service # check if service failed to load`

Or masking services:

`systemctl mask name.service`

There's a lot of good info on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903354/difference-between-systemctl-and-service) from Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Mind that although more powerful, `systemctl` is not a new version of `service`. It is not designed to replace `service`. Rather, `service` is designed as a high-level wrapper to "abstract" out various service managers like `init.d`, `initctl`, and (of course) `systemctl`.

Comment: I assume `service` was basically a wrapper for starting /etc/init.d scripts and they kept it around for "backward compatiility" with systemctl or something...

Answer (score 10):

`systemctl` is the main utility to control daemons/services in `systemd`,
while the `service` command is the traditional utility in `SysVinit` world.

One of systemd's features is to be compatible with SysVinit/legacy commands,
so, if you have the `systemctl` command,
 `service foo start` will be a wrapper around `systemctl start foo`.

Same story for `chkconfig`.