# Centos: systemctl vs service source

Tags: centos, php-fpm

The question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/867322/what-is-the-difference-between-service-and-systemctl) explain the main difference between `service` and `systemctl`. however, I have two versions of `php-fpm` installed and `service` is handling one version while `systemctl` is handling the other.

My question is, where can I access the config of each utility? from where each one of them read its data?

OS: Centos 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand well, but I think you are looking for these things.

For `service` command based check under `/etc/init.d/` and for `systemctl` check under `/etc/systemd/system` dir, you should see related init files to start/stop/reload with configuration and binary location of respective services.

Comment: You got me right, for services I found the related files, but nothing in `/etc/systemd/system` , any idea?

Comment: If service is managed by systemctl you should have link under 
 `/etc/systemd/system/<target>/`